# how to fit div into the corner

Tags: css, html

I have a div whose height span 2 rows. But I want to the following div fit into the bottom left and bottom right corner:

http://jsfiddle.net/netnet/NNH6V/
before browse, please drag the splitter to left and you will see the checkbox2 and "2222222222" could be fit into bottom left and bottom right perfectly.

I can use the relative position(.VerticalUp class). But the problem is it will leave a empty row underneath, which I don't want.

Any idea?

Comment: just a tip, you don't put `id's` on `</ >` tags.

Comment: which div do you want positioned in the bottom left and bottom right? be specific

Comment: I want checkbox2 and "22222222222222222" positioned in the bottom left and bottom right.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to float the Hematology div, you have two of them that are causing conflict. If you change .Hematology { float: right; }, this will make the Prenatal content float right...making everything fit...

Answer (score 0):

try float with position. 
ps-i'm new here. don't have much experience. :)

Comment: but it's not cross-browser compatible. even not resolution compatible

Answer (score 0):

Hey now change to your code as like this because your code is difficult i have created new code please check it. and implement your projects according design

**Css Code**

```
.top, .bottom{
list-style:none;
    color:#fff;
}


.top li, .bottom li{
    display:inline-block;
    background:green;
    width:33%;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-top:solid 10px red;
}
p{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.bottom {
position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}

.bottom li:last-child{
float:right;
}
```

**HTML code**

```
<ul class="top">
        <li>
        <input type="checkbox">
            <p>first Check box</p>
        </li>
        <li>
        <input type="checkbox">
            <p>Second Check box</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>finel box</p>
        </li>
    </ul>


<ul class="bottom">
        <li>
        <input type="checkbox">
            <p>first Check box</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>finel box</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

**Live demo** http://jsfiddle.net/fAkY5/

Comment: I think i didn't make myself clear. I don't want the 2nd row sit at the bottom of screen. the problem is the R1C2, the text is too long and span 2 rows. I want R2C1 and R2C2 fit into just beside the outstanding part of R1C2.